# Is "not >" equivalent to "<=" for a double

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

```
double a, b = ...;
```

Are the following C#-statements

```
!(a > b)
```

and

```
a <= b
```

equivalent or are there any numerical caveats?

Comment: `!(double.NaN > 1.0)` => true, `double.NaN <= 1.0` => false

Comment: They are equal in terms of expression. It called as [DeMorgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan_theorem) theorem. But in some cases it might not work. Like nullable values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are equivalent if they are standard vanilla double numeric values.

With nullable, NaN, etc, this isn't as clear.

**Consider**

```
double? a = null;
double b = 1;

if (!(a > b))
{
   //yes
}
if ((a <= b))
{
   //no
}
```

Or as [Marc Gravell♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) pointed out, the below demonstrates the exact same behaviour, while sticking with pure `double`:

```
double a = 42;
double b = double.NaN;
```